# SQL update from one table to another based on a group by condition

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables that only reference one column between them.

Equipment(E)

```
key
```

Job(J)

```
key
name
isdeleted
```

Table E needs to be updated with the minimum J.Key with the same J.Name where J.Deleted = 0. So in the following, E.Key = 18 would be updated to 12.

E

`18
3`

```
12, "This", 0
6, "This", 1
18, "This", 0
3, "That", 0
```

I think I need to update using min(key) and grouping by name and key where isdeleted - 0 but cannot figure how to put all of that together.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query to update `E` table (Please test it before executing it on PROD by doing select first instead of update)-

```
update E set
   E.[key] =
   (select min(J1.[key]) from Job J1 where J1.name = J.name and J1.isdeleted = 0)
from Equipment E
inner join Job J on J.[key] = E.[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by statements, as a previous user posted, but I thought I'd give you another option.

```
;with mins as
(     
    select      a.pid
                ,b.pid  min_pid
    from        #j  a
    cross apply (
                    select      top 1
                                b.*
                    from        #j  b
                    where       b.name = a.name
                            and b.isdeleted = 0
                    order by    b.pid
                )   b
    where       a.isdeleted = 0                     
)

update      a
set         pid = b.min_pid
from        #e      a
inner join  mins    b   on  b.pid = a.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach using a CTE to get the minimums:

```
WITH jobUpdates AS
(
    SELECT [key], 
           MIN([key]) OVER (Partition By Name) AS MinKey
    FROM jobs
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0
)

UPDATE e
SET e.[Key]
FROM equipment e
INNER JOIN jobUpdates j
    ON j.[key] = e.[key];
```